# When to use return, and what happens to returned data?

Tags: javascript, return

What is the difference between:

```
function bla1(x){console.log(x)}
```

and

```
function bla(x){return console.log(x)}
```

In which cases should I use `return`?

also, when a value is returned from a function, what happens to it? is it stored somewhere?

Comment: In general, if you are returning a value from a function you need to assign it to a compatible object/variable in the caller.

Answer (score 22):

> What is the difference

The first function returns `undefined` (as it does not `return` anything explicitly), the second one returns whatever `console.log` returns.

> In which cases should I use return?

When the function is generating some value and you want to pass it back to the caller. Take `Math.pow` for example. It takes two arguments, the base and the exponent and returns the base raised to the exponent.

> When a value is returned from a function, what happens to it? is it stored somewhere?

If you want to store the return value, then you have to assign it to a variable

```
var value = someFunction();
```

This stores the return value of `someFunction` in `value`. If you call the function without assigning the return value, then the value is just silently dropped:

```
someFunction();
```

---

These are programming basics and are not only relevant to JavaScript. You should find a book which introduces these basics and in particular for JavaScript, I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide). Maybe the Wikipedia article about [*Functions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28computer_science%29) is helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Beautifully answered and straight to the point. It made me finally understand the use of a return and what happens with that returned value. I always wondered what happened to the returned value.

Answer (score 7):

Return in a function is a way to pass back data from the function.

**Example:**

```
function test(){
   var test = 1+1;
   return test;
}

var feedback = test(); //feedback would now contain the value 2 if outputted.
```

We could also send a variable into the function and then return it back out.

**Example 2:**

```
 function test(i){
    i= i+1;
    return i;
 }

 var feedback = test(1); //feedback would also output the value 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, return gives you the possibility to call a function and save its returning value.

Here is a little example:

```
function bla(x) { return "blablabla"; }
```

If I call the method I will get a string with blablabla:

```
var blastring = bla(x);
alert(blastring);
```

This would result in an alert with blablabla.

Answer (score 0):

With `return` you specify what the value of a `function` is. You can use this value to do further operations or to store it into a variable and so on.

Since `console.log` `return`s `undefined`, the examples in your question are equivalent, as a `function` not reaching a return statement will return `undefined` as well. But let me give you an example:

```
function sum(arr) {
    var s = 0;
    for (var index in arr) {
        s += arr[index];
    }
    return s;
}

function prodsum(arr, scalar) {
    return scalar * sum(arr);
}

console.log(prodsum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3));
```

The result will be 165. If we remove the `return`s, then both `function`s will `return` `undefined`:

```
function sum(arr) {
    var s = 0;
    for (var index in arr) {
        s += arr[index];
    }
    s;
}

function prodsum(arr, scalar) {
    scalar * sum(arr);
}

console.log(prodsum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3));
```

and the result will be `undefined` as well. Basically, if you want the `function` to have a conclusion or final value, then you have a `return` in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add `return;` in the function. It stops the execution of the function.