# Calling function in object in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Trying ES6 and came across this example:

```
var bob = {
      _name: "Bob",
      _friends: ["Pete", "Joe", "Larry"],
      printFriends() {
        this._friends.forEach(f =>
          console.log(this._name + " knows " + f));
      }
    }
```

Console logging `bob.printFriends()` gives undefined.

Comment: are you sure you're transpiling the code correctly? It's working for me http://esnextb.in/?gist=87892ce1aac47ec0ff90540d0c546345

Comment: Well, `printFriends` does return `undefined`, so the result seems to be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
var bob = {
  _name: "Bob",
  _friends: ["Pete", "Joe", "Larry"],
  printFriends() {
    this._friends.forEach(f =>
      console.log(this._name + " knows " + f));
  }
}
bob.printFriends();
```

Output

```
"Bob knows Pete"
"Bob knows Joe"
"Bob knows Larry"
=> undefined
```

The reason you are seeing an `undefined` return value is because `printFriends` doesn't have a `return` statement.

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187114/when-to-use-return-and-what-happens-to-returned-data

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. Please see this fiddle and check the console. It's possible that you don't have the transpiler properly configured.

https://jsfiddle.net/e7rb9e4o/

```
bob.printFriends();
```

Output:

```
Bob knows Pete
Bob knows Joe
Bob knows Larry
```